# Updating seekbar stops audio while playing audio

Tags: android, audio, media

I am making an audio player and want to update seek bar while playing audio. I have searched online and written a method to update it using runOnUiThread but ***it stops the music while updating the seek bar***. How to solve it apart from using services.

```
 getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                int duration = mp.getCurrentPosition() / 1000;
                                seekbar.setProgress(duration);
                                    mHandler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
                                }
                            });
```

Answer (score 1):

you should do it like this

```
mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        int duration = mp.getCurrentPosition() / 1000;
        seekbar.setProgress(duration);
        mHandler.postDelayed(this,1000);
    }
},1000);
```

Comment: yes, it will only once, do you want it to run every 1 sec?

Comment: Yes, for every 1 sec.

Comment: It is same. What's the difference?

Comment: @mallaudin the above code looks working in your case, have a try on it

Comment: It is same. What's the difference?

Comment: @mallaudin try the above code, sorry for making the code too hard

Comment: What's the difference? Have a look at what I have posted.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Timer, example:

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
     @Override
     public void run() {
          int duration = mp.getCurrentPosition() / 1000;
          seekbar.setProgress(duration);
     }
}, 1000, 1000);
```

When you want cancel

```
timer.cancel();
timer = null;
```

[More info about Timer](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this); So put it in Your AudioControl() Method..... You dont set oncheckchangedlistner to your seekbar....